# Error Python con Flask: if no está especificado

Tags: python, flask

Tengo este código de python con flask y me gustaría saber por qué me da error:

```
from flask import Flask 

app = Flask (__name__)

app.route('/')
def home ():
    return 'Hello worls'

@app.route('/about')    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

El error que me sale es que if no está especificado.

Comment: Por favor, revisa el código que has pegado porque no se ve correctamente y por tanto es difícil ver cuál puede ser el error. Al pegar código en este sitio, pon en la línea anterior tres caracteres ```  y otros tres ``` al final del código, para que el sitio lo formatee correctamente.. Después verifica que se ve bien

De cualquier forma creo que el problema es que usas el decorador `@` para una ruta en un lugar donde no va seguido de una definición de función

Answer (score 2):

Dos cosas,

- 1-todas las rutas deberian retornar algo, por lo tantos tienes que definir una funcion que retorne algo
- 2-Debes decirle en que puerto del localhost, va a correr Flask

  app.run(port = 3000, debug = True)

El debug, hara que cada vez que realices un cambio en tu app.py , la app se reinicie

```
app = Flask (name)

app.route('/') 
def home (): 
    return 'Hello worls'

@app.route('/about')
def otrafuncion():
 mensaje='esta es otra funcion'

 return (mensaje)


if name == 'main': app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

EL código tiene errores en el name no tienes las rayas al piso o no lo copiaste bien, falto la @ en la ruta raíz entonces quedaría así:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask (__name__)

@app.route('/') 
def home (): 
    return 'Hello worls'

@app.route('/about')
def otrafuncion():
  mensaje='esta es otra funcion'    
  return (mensaje)


if __name__ == '__main__': 
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos errores, te falta el "@" en tu primer app.route, y tienes una segunda ruta (about) sin implementar. Con las correcciones quedaría así:

```
from flask import Flask 

app = Flask (__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello worls'

@app.route('/about')    
def about():
    return 'about'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask 

app = Flask (__name__)

app.route('/')
def home ():
    return 'Hello worls'

@app.route('/about')    

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run() <--------- debes colocar dentro de los parentesis (debug = True)
```

y al momento de correr el programa lo corres en la consola con ( `python nombredelarchivoprincipal.py` ) no lo corras con el comando ( `flask --app nombredelarchivoprincipal run`), funciona pero no activa el debug
ejemplo si el nombre del archivo .py principal es main.py seria asi ( `python main.py`) o (`flask --app main run`)

Comment: Este codigo presenta errores  no va a funcionar nunca